# Simple spinner item looks small in alertDialog

Tags: android, spinner

I made an alertDialog to get input from user. On the dialog i show a spinner to let the user select data. I used simple spinner item like this:

```
    spinnerCategories.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, CategorieNames));
```

And this is the image:

[image]

Items look pretty small or thin when you click on the spinner.
It definitely doesn't look like this spinner demo:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get to the example result?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it, i just had to replace this

```
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
```

with this:

```
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Thanks!

I use "Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem"